# Existence of a natural isomorphism given a functor and natural isomorphism.

Tags: category-theory

Let $F,G:C\to D$ be parallel functors such that there exists a natural isomorphism $\alpha:F\Rightarrow G$. Also, let $K:E\to C$ be a functor. Then there exists a natural isomorphism $\beta:FK\Rightarrow GK$.

Is this true? I think it should be. But I am unsure how to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Hint: We need to define a natural transformation $\beta$. So for every object $X$ in $E$, we need a map $\beta_X\colon F(K(X))\to G(K(X))$. Can you get such a map from $\alpha$? Now you just need to check that the maps $\beta_X$ cohere to a natural isomorphism, which will follow easily from the fact that $\alpha$ is a natural isomorphism.

Comment: Got it. I just needed an opinion. So, let $\beta_X:=\alpha_{K(X)}$ for all $X\in E$. Then, notice that $\beta_X$ has $\alpha_{K(X)}^{-1}$ as an inverse. This means that $\beta$ is a natural isomorphism. Now, is it also true that if $W:D\to J$ is a functor, then there exists a natural isomorphism $\omega:WF\Rightarrow WG$.

Comment: Yes, with components $\omega_X = W(\alpha_X)$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @JohnathonTaylor If you're satisfied with my answer, you can "accept" it by clicking the green check mark on the left.